# Latex printing single slash, backslash r, backslash n

Tags: escaping, latex, verbatim-string

I want the following line inside a *.tex file to be printed "as is":

```
while (tmp[0] == '\r' || tmp[0] == '\n') {tmp++;}
```

When I wrap it in a \verb command like this:

```
\verb"while (tmp[0] == '\r' || tmp[0] == '\n') {tmp++;}"
```

it doesn't work, and I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
```

All other google answers are **so** complicated.

Surely, there's got to be an easy way to do this, right?
Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is the minimal counter example requested in the comments:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% document class: beamer %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{beamer}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% no navigation bars please %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% no navigation symbols please %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% no footers at all please %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% center the title please %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% begin document %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%
% title %
%%%%%%%%%
\title{Some Title}   

%%%%%%%%%%
% author %
%%%%%%%%%%
\author{Some Author}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% date ... %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\date{\today} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% frame ... %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frame{\titlepage} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% SECTION :: Introduction %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Section Introduction} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Frame Title :: Introduction %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frame{\frametitle{Status}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Items :: Begin %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{itemize}
\item
while (tmp[0] == 'A' $||$ tmp[1] == 'B') $\{$tmp++;$\}$
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @rkta I have added a minimal counter example where that happens.

Comment: @rkta no, it looks like what they solve there is a problem of too long verbatim lines ... but if I make it shorter it's still a problem ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print an actual backslash in LaTeX you use the command `\backslash`, so for your code:

```
while (tmp[0] == '\backslash r' || tmp[0] == '\backslash n') {tmp++;}
```

**EDIT:** I forgot you need this command in math mode. If you want everything "as is", this is the code you need (for the vertical lines and the curly brackets as well):

```
while (tmp[0] == `$\backslash$r' $\|$ tmp[0] == `$\backslash$n') $\{$tmp++;$\}$
```

[image: This gives this ouput]